# Running code from a webapp within a Google Sheet script

Tags: web-applications, google-sheets-query

I am trying to create a room booking thing for a school that I work at.
If I leave the google sheet unprotected it is very easy for users to destroy the formulas on the spreadsheet. However if I lock it to only myself then they are unable to use the spreadsheet. The idea is to lock editing to myself and then have the code run as me.

I have read the only way to run code as myself is through a web app. I have created the doGet function and when I follow the link to the web app this works perfectly, I get the "success" message and the spreadsheet is altered (The current doGet is a draft just to test its functionality). However when using the UrlFetchApp command nothing happens at all. I have authorised everything that I have been prompted.

Please ignore any unnecessary lines or bad coding, I am completely new to this. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
function onOpen()
{ 
 
    
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Book Room').addItem('Book Room', 'Userinterface').addToUi(); 
  
     
  
}
function Userinterface() 
{
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.setTitle("RoomBooking");
  
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var label = app.createLabel();
  
  var textbox = app.createTextBox();
  textbox.setName("txt1");
  
  var button = app.createButton("Submit");
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("Clickevent");
  button.addClickHandler(handler);
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  
  panel.add(textbox);
  panel.add(button);
  
  
  app.add(panel);
  
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}
function Clickevent(e)
{
  
  var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/a/st-swithuns.portsmouth.sch.uk/macros/s/AKfycbwEsUsHJ2_1VwWqu1nTh1ux2FkEwP5ul2OXBc2pTQs8Z1eV_ls/exec");
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var textvalue = e.parameter.txt1;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow() - 11;
  var column = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn() -2;
  if(row <=0 || row >=6 || column <=0  || column >= 8){Browser.msgBox("Please choose a cell within the booking grid.");return;}
  var finalcolumn = row*7+column-4
  var search = sh.getRange(1,26).getValue(); 
  var finalrow =1;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Database');
  
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) 
{
  if(sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue() == search){break;}
  finalrow +=1;
  
}
  if(sheet.getRange(finalrow, finalcolumn).getValue() == "")
  {
  sheet.getRange(finalrow, finalcolumn).setValue(textvalue);
   
  }
  else{Browser.msgBox("This room has already been booked on time and date."); return;}
  
  
 
  return app.close();
}
function doGet(e)
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1eOqf1Cofkz9u0Zg2UIb9Ana3VQC5PN0aZqWQkip2d2w").getSheetByName('Bookings').getRange('A1').setValue("hihihihihihi");
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success")
}
```